# Лодыжка и щиколотка

Tags: лексика

Лодыжка и щиколотка - два слова, обозначающие одну и ту же часть тела. Есть ли различия в значениях? Какое слово появилось в русском языке раньше и почему появилось второе?

Comment: Я всегда считала, что щиколотки - это выступающие по бокам косточки. А лодыжки - это сустав, сгибающаяся часть. Например, при покупке узких штанцов, нужны замеры: длина штанины до щиколотки, а обхват лодыжки 25 см. Кстати, вот кто-то (я тут первый раз, ещё не разобралась как, что и кто тут) писал, что эта часть тела называется голеностоп. Значит, соединяет стопу и голень. Значит эта часть, от щиколоток до колена, называется голень? Вся? Или только спереди? При покупке тех же джинсов (или джинс?), нужно сделать замеры в области икр? Или голени?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Лодыжка и щиколотка - два слова, обозначающие одну и ту же часть тела.

Не совсем так. Щиколотка - это выступ, холмик, внешний видимый элемент.
Лодыжка - сам сустав, включая и его внутреннюю часть.
Но это не слишком принципиальное различие.

Оба слова неясного происхождения, исходные формы - лодыга и щиколка (высказывается версия о прямой связи последнего с "лодыга", но недостоверно)

по Фасмеру:

лоды́га лоды́жка, укр. лоди́га, блр. лоды́га "лодыжка; полый стебель", чеш. lоdуhа, польск. ɫоdуgа " стебель"; ср. др.-русск. лодыга " альчик, бабка" (Новгор. поучение ХII в.; см. РФВ 24, 349). Неясно. Недостоверно заимствование из польск., вопреки Брюкнеру (KZ 48, 206); неприемлемо также объяснение из лат. lасtūса " латук", вопреки Преобр. (I, 464), Голубу (138), или из д.-в. н. lоtа, sumarlota (sumarlatta) " ветка", вопреки Горяеву (ЭС 189), Миклошичу (Мi. ЕW 172), Маценауэру (57); см. Бернекер 1, 727. Столь же маловероятно родство с ло́дка, вопреки Брюкнеру (310).

щи́колка щи́колотка, укр. щи́колоток, род. п. -тка – то же. Связь с лоды́га (Горяев, ЭС 429 и сл.) недостоверна. Весьма сомнительно сравнение первой части (там же) с лат. сiссum "кожура граната, ничто", заимствованным из греч. κίκκος, которое считают иноязычным (Гофман, Gr. Wb. 144; Вальде–Гофм. I, 241 и сл.; Буазак 454; Мейе–Эрну 212). Точно так же весьма сомнительно родство со щеко́лда.

Answer (score 4):

Как реабилитолог, знающий анатомию, и как переводчик не соглашусь с указанными выше значениями.
Лодыжки — это выступающие костные бугорки с обеих сторон голеностопного сустава. Часто область самого голеностопного сустава называют лодыжкой, но это очень простонародно и некорректно. Лодыжек две — наружная и внутренняя, это выступы по обе стороны голеностопного сустава.
Щиколоткой называют также либо область голеностопного сустава, либо выступ изнутри или снаружи него. Но ни то, ни другое слово не корректно использовать в текстах научной направленности для обозначения места перехода голени в стопу, поскольку и лодыжка, и щиколотка — лишь составные части этого соединения.
Я бы использовала слово "голеностоп" для обозначения этой части тела, хоть оно и не применяется широко, но для более серьезных текстов подходит куда лучше щиколоток и лодыжек.

Comment: Все это очень хорошо, но в чем таки разница между лодыжкой и щиколоткой? Мы тут прежде русским языком интересуемся, а не анатомическими подробностями. А что касается собственно названий и объектов, то тут такая штука, что в бытовом языке по разным причинам часто укрепляются не совсем верные с научной точки зрения представления. Вот "плечо" например. Это не просто сустав, это чаще всего некая область, на которой погоны носят. Бороться с этим не надо, надо просто иметь ввиду разницу подходов.

Comment: @Мимоходов *надо просто иметь ввиду разницу подходов* — согласен, но чтобы иметь её ввиду, нужно знать оба подхода. Поддержал ответ, потому как научный стиль языка пока не запрещён :)

Comment: @grizzly стиль не запрещен, но если за стилем не видно сути... Вы вот лично поняли, в чем эта разница состоит? Что именно по мнению LadyOlly  надо называть лодыжкой, а что - щиколоткой? С научной точки зрения. А ведь вопрос стоял именно так, в чем эта разница.

Comment: @Мимоходов Да, понял. Лодыжки — это, грубо говоря, две косточки, выступающие внутрь и наружу. Щиколотка — это скорее обиходный термин, который обозначает что-то более общее (менее конкретное) и в научном стиле этот термин лучше не употреблять. Даже если я понял не совсем правильно, уверен, что раньше я понимал ещё хуже.

Comment: @grizzly  Нда? Ну значит, я придираюсь. Если бы я что-то подобное рассмотрел в тексте... Yе важно, согласился ли бы, придирок бы не было. Ясно, спасибо.

Answer (score 1):

Нашла такое мнение (не поручусь за его правильность), что в лодыжка — медицинское понятие, а слова "щиколотка" в медицине нет. "Щиколотка" — простонародное название лодыжки.

Comment: Да, я тоже только это и смогла найти. Интересует лингвистический и исторический контекст.

Comment: исторический контекст в сапожном деле. До сих пор туфли лодочками называют.
в обоих словах этот корень присутствует. В слове щиколотка--это часть сапога прикрывающая--щека--кость от повреждения, задник, делается из толстой кожи и почти вровень с выступом, но чтоб не мешала движению.
смысловая нагрузка обуви в похожести на лодку. колодка-это это модель будущего сапога.
слишком много букофф русского языка никогда не бывают лишними, если применить его знание.

Comment: "Агащаз"... Любая женщина вам объяснит, что "лодочками" туфли называют по форме самой обуви.  
А лодыжка и тем более колодка тут рядом не лежала. Вр всяком случае никакой разумной связи (этимологической) не просматривается.

Зато сама "лодка" очевидно родственна "ладье". 
Ну можно еще  - с очень малой вероятностью - провести ряд к "лад", "ладить" или "ложке" (повторяю, это "в порядке бреда"). 

Но уж лодыга совершенно точно не из этого ряда.